# Unix: SCP (over SSH) fails due to interactive promot

Tags: ssh, scp

I have this problem:
I have a server to which I ssh, and it has a special prompt request. The prompt is done by a ?prompt command.

It is fine with SSH, since the prompt I guess gets some input, but when I use SCP, the copy always fails.

So, I was wondering if there is maybe a flag for ssh and scp - so that interactive prompts are ignored.

(By the way, I need the prompt, so removing it isn't an option).
THANKS.

Comment: Is this about programming? If not, then you are on the wrong site.

Answer (score 0):

The prompt and response go into SSH stdio channels that are what `scp` uses to talk to the remote slave `scp` process, so it breaks the hand-shaking, and the transfer is aborted.

The right way to add additional prompts to SSH connections is through the `keyboard-interactive` authentication mechanism, probably with the help of some PAM module.

Your current approach just cripples SSH beyond simple usage patterns.